# Sending Data via a Local Network

Tags: networking, data-transfer

I'm sure there is a very easy answer to this but I'm struggling to search for the answer on Google due to missing crucial technical knowledge and terminology.

If I have two phones that are 1km apart can I set up a local wifi network that doesnt need internet but can send and receive data back and forth between the phones? Or is it not wifi and something else?

Comment: what kind of phones?

Answer (score 2):

1 km not possible through WiFi because WiFi range is efficient in 650meters & to transmit data from one mobile to another mobile without Internet you can try the protocol called zigbee or else am not pretty sure about it try MQTT broker and raspberry pi to done the specific option

Answer (score 1):

You can set up two wireless access points (ie, "routers") configured to route data between each other's clients via some longer range scheme.

Typical wired Ethernet would not reach that far, but something like fiber optic (if you have right of way to run it) or microwave (if you have line of sight) could be used to bridge between them.

You may however find that it's cheaper to simply purchase Internet service at both locations and route through that; this would probably cost less than a traditional solution like a leased line.  However, if you do this you may want some sort of tunneling scheme like a VPN to bridge them, without allowing in unauthorized traffic from others.